# Await one of two futures in tokio

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await

I have two futures that I can await. However, I only want to wait for the first of the two to finish, and do other things as soon as that happens.
Is there a way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to do something different for each future, or just wait for the first?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Update: Sorry, I overlooked at it.

In Rust with Tokio, you can achieve a similar result using the tokio::select! macro. Here's an example:

```
use tokio::time::{sleep, Duration};

async fn task1() {
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
    println!("Task 1 complete");
}

async fn task2() {
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    println!("Task 2 complete");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Spawn two tasks
    let handle1 = tokio::spawn(task1());
    let handle2 = tokio::spawn(task2());

    // Wait for the first task to complete
    tokio::select! {
        _ = handle1 => {
            println!("Task 1 completed first");
        }
        _ = handle2 => {
            println!("Task 2 completed first");
        }
    }

    // You can continue with other tasks or code here
}
```

In this example, tokio::select! is used to wait for the first task to complete. The macro will select the first task that finishes, and you can then proceed with the specific logic for that task.

Ensure that your Cargo.toml file includes the necessary dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
```

I hope this will clear your question.

Old:
Yes, you can achieve this using asynchronous programming concepts, such as async/await in languages like C#. You can use the Task.WhenAny method to wait for the completion of the first task. Here's a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Create two tasks
        Task<int> task1 = Task.Run(() => { return TaskMethod(1); });
        Task<int> task2 = Task.Run(() => { return TaskMethod(2); });

        // Wait for the first task to complete
        Task<int> firstCompletedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2);

        // Print the result of the completed task
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {firstCompletedTask.Result} completed first.");

        // You can continue with other tasks or code here
    }

    static int TaskMethod(int taskId)
    {
        Task.Delay(taskId * 1000).Wait(); // Simulating some work
        Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} complete");
        return taskId;
    }
}
```

In this example, Task.WhenAny is used to wait for the first task to complete. The result of the completed task is then printed. You can replace the TaskMethod with your actual asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method,

```
 function asyncTask1() {
        return new <MethodName>(resolve => {
            
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("Async Task 1 completed");
                resolve("Result, Async Task 1");
            }, <mention time>); 
        });
    }
```

This method help to wait the task to complete one by one.

```
    <MethodName>.race([asyncTask1(), asyncTask2(),asyncTask3(),...])
        .then(result => {
            console.log("First task completed", result);
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("An error occurred:", error);
        });
```